# dynamic proxies in Application servers and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, proxy, application-server

In my understanding proxies are the key of the inner working of application servers
and framewroks such as Spring, generally speaking they are used to implement the behaviour requested by annotated methods (such as trancation propagation and so on).

Dynamic proxies let the developers not care about their exsistence, in fact developers never see proxies' code.

My question is: if dynamic proxies didn't exsist, how would things work ?
My best guess is that they should be generated statically and being deployed   inside the war perhaps along with the rest of application classes.
Can you confirm or prove my guess wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score -1):

Dynamic proxies are created during runtime using java reflection through class java.lang.reflect.Proxy , here after an example from the javadoc of how to create a proxy.

> Proxy provides static methods for creating dynamic proxy classes and
>   instances, and it is also the superclass of all dynamic proxy classes
>   created by those methods.
>
> To create a proxy for some interface Foo:
>
> ```
>  InvocationHandler handler = new MyInvocationHandler(...);
>  Class proxyClass = Proxy.getProxyClass(
>      Foo.class.getClassLoader(), new Class[] { Foo.class });
>  Foo f = (Foo) proxyClass.
>      getConstructor(new Class[] { InvocationHandler.class }).
>      newInstance(new Object[] { handler });
> ```